# Info about Elton–Odell theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Hello everyone, could anyone please tell me where can I find information about the Elton–Odell theorem?

It states:

For any infinite dimensional Banach space $X$ there is a $q > 1$ so that $X$ contains a sequence $(x_n)$ with $\|x_n\|=1$ and $\|x_n-x_m\|\ge q$, whenever $m\ne n$.

Thanks

Comment: The original paper: MR0633103 (82k:46025)
Elton, J.; Odell, E.
The unit ball of every infinite-dimensional normed linear space contains a $(1+\varepsilon )$-separated sequence.
Colloq. Math. 44 (1981), no. 1, 105--109.
46B20 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J. Diestel, Sequences and series in Banach spaces, Springer-Verlag, New York, 1984.
(Chapter XIV, page 241)

Comment: thx a lot!!!!!!